# Python ncurses get relative pad pos shown and edit

Tags: python, ncurses

So I am using a pad for message input in a chat program and I have turned on auto-scrolling for the pad with pad.scrollok() and pad.idlok().

When I call pad.refresh(pad_pos, 0, etc...), the first 2 arguments indicate that I should attach the coordinate on the pad associated with (pad_pos,0)  as (y,x) coordinates to the begin position (y,x) in the terminal indicated in the other arguments of the refresh call.

The problem I am having is that when the pad scrolls automatically as a result turning on autoscrolling, pad_pos isn't updated.  Yet it does in fact scroll text up on the screen as I type more.  I assume this is because curses is storing some relative pad position in the background that it is adding on to my given arguments in the refresh call, but I am unsure how I can access this relative position or change it.  The reason I want to change it is so that I can make the text scroll back down when I am deleting characters from the input.

Any ideas?